# Android studio error clase envolvente como lo soluciono?

Tags: android-studio

- Buenas tengo este codigo..Me sale: error: not an enclosing class:
  MainActivity
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
  Probe con el this solo no funciona tampoco, me pide un constructor. Lo he probado y quiero que primero me salga
  el splash y luego el login...Sino al reves funciono...

  ```
                          package com.example.relevamientovisual;

                          import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

                          import android.content.Intent;
      import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.Handler; import android.view.WindowManager;

  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
          this.getWindow().setFlags(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
          );

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
          new Handler().postDelayed(
                  new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                          startActivity(intent);
                          finish();
                      }

                      ;
                  }, 5000);
      } }
  ```

Comment: `startActivity` debe ejecutarse desde el hilo de la UI. [Pasa el parámetro `Looper.getMainLooper()` al `Handler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28089859/13419694) y mira si funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es el contexto, usa `MainActivity.this` en lugar de unicamente `this`:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    ;
                }, 

        5000);
```

Debes hacer referencia a la Activity desde donde se realizará el `Intent`.